# Replace data in google sheet based on a mapping table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sheet1 is the sheet that's changing-

[image]

Sheet2 is directing the change

[image]

I am looking to replace the data in column A of Sheet1 with the Column B of Sheet2. Basically similar to VLOOKUP however, if I use VLOOKUP I will need to create additional column to use that formula, which is not the goal.

Expected Result Sheet1:

[image]

Comment: That does not seem very complicated what is keeping you from accomplishing your goal?

Comment: It is not difficult if I do find and replace manually. However this is a very simplified example. The dataset is quite huge and am looking for either some formula or an automated script. @Cooper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set the sheet names for `sheet1` and `sheet2`. In this case, `sheet1` and `sheet2` are `Sheet1 is the sheet that's changing-` and `Sheet2 is directing the change` in your question, respectively.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet1 = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.
  const sheet2 = "Sheet2"; // Please set sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [s1, s2] = [sheet1, sheet2].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  const s1Range = s1.getRange("A1:A" + s1.getLastRow());
  const s2Obj = s2.getRange("A1:B" + s2.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {});
  const res = s1Range.getValues().map(([a]) => [s2Obj[a] || a]);
  s1Range.setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the column "A" of `sheet1" is modified using the values of columns "A" and "B" of` sheet2`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)